# How to pass parameters in Twilio's outbound calls?

Tags: twilio

I believe Twilio's outbound call could be HTTP POST request. Is there a way I can pass my custom POST body (json etc) when making outbound voice call request? I'm writing a generic call center where I would like to pass the conversation workflow when making outbound calls so that the code which receives the call knows how to run the conversation. I looked at the documentation (https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/twilio_request) and looks like we can only pass standard parameters (from, to etc). Thanks for any help.

Comment: A similar question was asked before- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31117701/passing-variables-to-outbound-call-twiml?rq=1

Comment: I know I can use database etc to store/retrieve the workflow but that would be an unwanted workaround.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the only parameter you can customize is the *Url Parameter*.

Your JSON is pretty much a string (you might have to url encode it and also watch for the length), but you could put it in the query string of the *Url Parameter*.

```
?json=url_encoded_json
```

Comment: Thanks Alex, but this won't work as we would be limited by Url length. The workflow I'm thinking to support here would consist of lengthy conversation e.g. say this if user press 1, say that user press 2 etc etc.

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to keep the workflows on your server side, map them with an id, pass the id in Url, retrieve the workflow on the call handler page based on the id. Maybe in the future Twilio will let us pass our custom form parameters.

Comment: Yeah, +1 for future request. That way we wont have extra network hops thus better latency.